# Cassandra truncates milliseconds with LocalDate

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I have been trying to store the timestamp value till millisecond in Cassandra but I am able to get only till LocalDate by DataStax driver, the millisecond part is being omitted by it.

This is my class

```
package com.example.connectCass.Model;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;
import com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate;


import java.util.Date;


@Data
@Table
public class DemoModel {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "acctID", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String acctID;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "transactionDate", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private LocalDate transactionDate;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "currentTime", type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private LocalDate currentTime;

    @Column
    private String card;

    @Column
    private String amountCreditedFrom;

    @Column
    private double transactionAmount;

    @Column
    private double balance;

    public void setTransactionDate(){
        this.transactionDate = LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch(new Date().getTime());
    }

    public void setCurrentTime(){
        this.currentTime = LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch(new Date().getTime());
    }
}
```

In the `setCurrentTime` method, I want the time till milisecond, but not able to do it, it's only getting till today's date. Tried the `java.util.Date` directly but it's not working.

Why are milliseconds not present in Cassandra?

Comment: What do you mean by _time till milisecond_ and _till today's date_? Please rephrase.

Comment: It means like, toTimestamp(now()) gives value till, current milliseconds in Cassandra, same I want to have in Java and store in Cassandra, and till today date mean the time precision is till today date not till milliseconds.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to express. `new Date().getTime()` returns `1586787833411` a few seconds ago, which is the number of milliseconds since epoch. What value did you want or were expecting?

Comment: In Java it is fine, I am getting value, problem is storing that value in Cassandra, with mili second with cassandra timestamp datatype

Comment: While storing in Cassandra , I am only able to store the java milisecond with days precision, the hour, second, milisecond is gone, something like 1586787800000, hope u get it now

Comment: `LocalDate` doesn't have a time component.

Comment: Use a `java.time.Instant` and a `timestamp` column type.

Comment: Ok will try and update ☺️

Comment: Not working :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had mistakenly defined Date in my table schema instead of Timestamp, my bad.